# Python: How to deal with a csv that doesn't have commas at the end of the row?

Tags: csv, pandas, dataframe

I have about 100 CSV's that all contain data from varying sources and therefore have different delimiters. Is there a python library that can guess at a CSV's structure?

For example, somebody had a table like this:

```
color, shape, avg weight, 
red, square, 15g, 
blue, circle, 11g,
```

And the csv they saved looked like:

```
'color', 'shape', 'avg weight', 'red', 'square', '15g', 'blue', 'circle', '11g'
```

If I know the number of columns (which I figure out using a function) I can just create a list of lists and then make it a `pandas DataFrame`.

However, many of the people have data that has no comma at the end of the row, like this:

```
color, shape, avg weight 
red, square, 15g 
blue, circle, 11g
```

And the CSV's they send look like:

```
'color', 'shape', 'avg weight' 'red', 'square', '15g' 'blue', 'circle', '11g'
```

It gets even worse when there is no value in the `avg weight` like:

```
color, shape, avg weight 
red, square,
blue, circle, 11g
```

which results in a CSV that looks like:

```
'color', 'shape', 'avg weight' '', 'square', '15g' 'blue', 'circle', '11g'
```

How do I deal with this? Or what is a library I can explore?

Comment: Fix your data.  You need a consistent structure, or it's nearly impossible to program a parser.

Comment: That's not an option for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you at least are sure about the quotes, this approach may work. The idea is to match the quoted expressions with a regular expression and then exploit our knowledge about the number of columns to form the dataframe. If you don't know the number of columns in advance and you can't rely on the quotes I think there is no reasonable way to reconstruct the data without newlines.

```
import re
import pandas

s = "'color', 'shape', 'avg weight' '', 'square', '15g' 'blue', 'circle', '11g'"

Ncols = 3
r = re.compile("'([^']*)'")
items = r.findall(s)
table = [items[i*Ncols:i*Ncols+Ncols] for i in range(len(items)//Ncols)]

df = pandas.DataFrame(table[1:], columns=table[0])
```